# JSON libs for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, json, openshift

I am trying to connect to a OpenShift PHP database that I already set up. I am trying to connect to it using a eclipse java class. I tried to use Google Http client files but I am not sure how to add these into my project. I tried adding in via a libs folder but it always shows a error. Can anyone guide me on this?

Comment: What error does it show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the library to your classpath in your project project properties.

Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries

Put the jar in your libs folder and add a jar in the libraries settings.  If you only get the source, then you have to add the source package to your source folder and everything should be fine.  Alternatively you can link the source in externally.  However, you should be getting the library as a jar so just throw that in the libs folder and add it in your project properties.